# Is there any passive component holder similar to a fuse holder?

Tags: pcb, components, testing, fuse-holders

Below is a fuse holder from Keystone. As far as I know, it allows the user to replace the fuse inside easily when it is needed.

[image]

My question is, is there similar holder for regular SMD passive components, such as 0603 holder, 1206 holder and so on?

For example, If I would like to test a part of my board with different capacitors, I could simply plug out the capacitor and replace with a new one, instead of soldering and unsoldering it. I know soldering a component is really not much of work, but i am imaging with such holder, it is much faster for testing, it saves time to replace components without any extra eletrical equipments.

I tried to search it on Digikey but only found fuse holders and LED holders. I guess there must be a reason why this is not popular (or it does exist with some special names?), thus I hope someone can maybe give me a explanation or insight of this idea?

Comment: why use SMD when you're not trying to **S**urface-**M**ount **D**evices? Sounds like this plan has a bit of a hole. Depending on the application, the typical *purpose* of a capacitor is counteracted by having a holder between the capacitor and what it's used for.

Comment: You could use a breadboard - designed for building temporary circuits and easy to change components and the circuit.

Comment: Just solder them in and out.  There aren't any holders that I know of.  SMD parts are fragile, and wouldn't survive very long going in and out of clips.

Comment: For a single component, I've put a part on the pads and used a wooden stick to hold it in contact with the pads.  Didn't even solder it.  That was enough to find the right value then grab a fresh part and solder it on.

Answer (score -2):

You could try using female header pins. It's not exactly what they are designed for, but as long as the legs of the passive components are thick enough, it should do for testing. I found these on Digi-Key: https://www.digikey.com.au/product-detail/en/sullins-connector-solutions/PPTC021LFBN-RC/S7000-ND/810142

Comment: Will that work with SMD as in the OP’s question?

Comment: @HandyHowie I realised after posting that the OP was only asking about SMD, and not all components. I doubt it would work with SMD without adding leads to them (which I guess is still easier than removing and replacing components), but decided to leave the answer up.